# Retrieving CoreMotion data in background with CoreLocation at a specified time interval

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, background-process, core-motion

I have a car app that needs to track CoreMotion and CoreLocation data at a specified time interval(0.5 seconds) in both foreground and background. The user controls the start and stop of the tracking, so we don't have to worry about battery life issues. Here's what I currently have:

```
var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
var motionManager:CMMotionManager?

override init() {
    super.init()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
}

//Call this to start tracking
func startTracking() {
    motionManager?.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
}
//Call this to stop tracking
func stopTracking(){
    locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    motionManager?.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
}

//Using CoreLocation delegate method to retrieve both motion and location data.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last{
        if let data = motionManager?.deviceMotion {
            print("Data: \(data) Location:\(location)")
        }
    }
}
```

This issue that I'm having now is that I can't control how frequent location update occurs in order to get my CoreMotion data. I need to track CoreMotion data every 0.5 seconds in the background, the CoreLocation data doesn't have to be frequent. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response but to set an interval of updates you should write:

```
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.5
```